# Count of occurences of multiple values in array of string column in spark <2.2 and scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to find a count of occurrences of specific elements present in array, we can use `array_contains` function but I am looking for another solution that can work below spark 2.2

**Input:**

```
+----+------------------+
|col1|        array_col2|
+----+------------------+
|   x|   [1, 2, 3, 7, 7]|
|   z|[3, 2, 8, 9, 4, 9]|
|   a|      [4, 5, 2, 8]|
+----+------------------+
```

`result1` -> count of occuriencies of `1,2` in a given array column `array_col2`

`result2` -> count of occuriencies of `3,7,9` in a given array column `array_col2`

**Expected Output:**

```
+----+------------------+----------+----------+ 
|col1|        array_col2|   result1|   result2| 
+----+------------------+----------+----------+ 
|   x|   [1, 2, 3, 7, 7]|         2|         3| 
|   z|[3, 2, 8, 9, 4, 9]|         1|         3| 
|   a|      [4, 5, 2, 8]|         1|         0| 
+----+------------------+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use UDF :

```scala
val count_occ = udf((s: Seq[Int], f: Seq[Int]) => s.filter(f.contains(_)).size)

val df1 = df.withColumn(
    "result1",
    count_occ($"array_col2", array(lit(1), lit(2)))
  ).withColumn(
    "result2",
    count_occ($"array_col2", array(lit(3), lit(7), lit(9)))
  )

df1.show
//+----+------------------+-------+-------+
//|col1|        array_col2|result1|result2|
//+----+------------------+-------+-------+
//|   x|   [1, 2, 3, 7, 7]|      2|      3|
//|   z|[3, 2, 8, 9, 4, 9]|      1|      3|
//|   a|      [4, 5, 2, 8]|      1|      0|
//+----+------------------+-------+-------+
```

You can also explode the array then groupby and count :

```
val df1 = df.withColumn(
    "col2",
    explode($"array_col2")
  ).groupBy("col1", "array_col2").agg(
    count(when($"col2".isin(1, 2), 1)).as("result1"),
    count(when($"col2".isin(3, 7, 9), 1)).as("result2")
  )
```